# How can I get a vertical navbar to not take up space on smartphone when collapsed?

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I have a horizontal navbar, it shows as collapsed on my smart phone, taking up just the vertical space for the toggle icon. However when I try to create a vertical navbar, the best I've been able to get is to have the toggle icon take up the entire column.

I have an existing site that I'm converting to bootstrap 4.3.1 so it will work better on smartphones. You can see my experiments at http://www.lionsclub.ca/, where I post the latest version of the main page so I can test it from my smartphone. I just make sure that it isn't totally broken before I copy a new version.

I want the navbar to be on the left, with the main content on the right so the navbar and main content are in a . If I don't do this, I can't get the main content to float to the right of the navbar.

In order to get the navbar to be expanded on computer screens, I have to specify class navbar-expand-md for the nav element, which then seems to require me to specify class flex-column for the ul navbar element. When I do this, the navbar shows up properly, with the collapse toggle absent on larger screens but showing on smartphones. I can then toggle the menu if I want to see it.

However, to get the second div (for the main content) to show up to the right, I have to specify something like col-9 as its class (if I go larger, it doesn't float on the right). Flex-column doesn't work.

When I do this, things behave almost reasonably. However the collapsed navbar occupies the full column, taking up a lot of screen space. Is there a way to get it to collapse to a floated element in the top left corner of the enclosing ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" title="West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club home page">&nbsp;home&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-9">
    some content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I said, the code works but doesn't behave the way I'd like. I really want the collapsed navbar to occupy no more space than the toggle icon. The same problem exists with a horizontal navbar but is less objectionable because the horizontal content vanishes when scrolled. The vertical content always takes up space.

Does anyone know a way to make this work better than what I've come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using 2 divs with `col-[xx]-[99]` inside the `<div class='row'>` which can do this for you...

- for the left navigation, we use: `<div class='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3'> ... </div>`
- for the right content area, we use: `<div class='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9'> ... </div>`
- you won't get images loaded in the snippet below because you're not using HTTPS (which you should)

working **snippet below**:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .bg-light {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://www.lionsclub.ca/scripts/email.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lionsclub.ca/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</link>

<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://www.lionsclub.ca/images/LionBanner.png" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3'>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" title="West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club home page">&nbsp;home&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html" title="a history of the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;about&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="activities.html" title="ongoing activities of the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions club">&nbsp;activities&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html" title="how to contact the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;contact&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="events.html" title="upcoming events of the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;events&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="join.html" title="how to join the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;join&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="links.html" title="other community organizations">&nbsp;links&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="members.html" title="current members of the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;members&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="news.html" title="latest news from the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club">&nbsp;news&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="partners.html" title="our community partners">&nbsp;Community
                                Partners&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.a711lions.org/" title="Lions Club district web site">&nbsp;Lions&nbsp;District&nbsp;A-711&nbsp;</a><br />&nbsp;
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.lionsclubs.org/" title="The Lions Clubs International"><img src="http://a711lions.ca/images/LCI_primary_sig_2color_web.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.dogguides.com/" title="The Lions Foundation of Canada"><img src="images/dogguides.gif" alt="Lions Foundation of Canada logo" /></a><br />&nbsp;
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.lcif.org/" title="Lions Clubs International Foundation">
                <img src="http://www.a711lions.ca/images/lcif_h3c.gif" alt="LCIF logo" />
              </a>
              <br />&nbsp;
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/WestHillHighlandCreekLionsClub" title="follow us on Facebook">
                <img id="followus" src="http://www.lionsclub.ca/images/facebook-icon.png" alt="follow us on Facebook" />
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9">
      <!-- start of inserted content -->
      <div class="hot">

        <a href="http://www.lionsclub.ca/rainbarrel.html" title="rain barrel sale">
          <img src="http://www.lionsclub.ca/images/rainbarrel.jpg" alt="rain barrel image" style="float: left;" />
          <h6>Lions rainbarrel sale</h6>
          <h6>Order from Stock!</h6>
        </a>
        <h4>New Stock!</h4>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

      </div>
      Welcome to the West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club's web site. It's fun to be a Lion! We hope you'll join us.</p>
      <p>The Club was chartered on November&nbsp;3,&nbsp;1944 and has been active in the community ever since. The club started the community's first newspaper and built the original <a href="https://www.toronto.ca/data/parks/prd/facilities/complex/2025/index.html">Heron Park
                        Community Centre</a>, which it later donated to the City.</p>
      <p>We normally meet on the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> Tuesdays of each month (except for July &amp; August when we don't meet, and June &amp; December when we skip the last meeting) at the <a href="https://www.toronto.ca/data/parks/prd/facilities/complex/2025/index.html">Heron Park
                        Community Centre</a> (<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=292+Manse+Road,Toronto,+ON&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=114.541383,98.261719&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwloc=addr&om=1">292
                        Manse Road</a> South of Lawrence) at 7:00&nbsp;PM. If you're not a member and would like to be a guest, contact us at the e-mail address below.</p>
      <p><button onclick="initMailtoButton('secretary','');" style="border: 0px; margin:0px; padding: 0px;">Contact the club via e-mail</button>.<br />&nbsp;
      </p>
      <!-- end of inserted content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Serving the community since 1944</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="copyright">copyright &copy; West Hill - Highland Creek Lions Club&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```